# How to insert a line of Java from a text file into my Java code

Tags: java

I have a text file that contains many similar lines to this one

> System.out.println(13);

I would like to insert this into my Java code so that when I run the program, it will output 13.

Here is the program where it would just output `System.out.println(13);` instead of `13`:

```
File sampleCode = new File("sample.txt");
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(sampleCode);
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println(scan.nextLine()); //this is where i plan to insert the lines from the .txt file
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: If you're trying to compile-and-execute arbitrary Java source code, that may or may not compile with `javac`, then probably the easiest solution is to use the [JShell API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/jdk.jshell/module-summary.html).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?